# Hiding apps in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to write a logic to hide app launcher icon from the app list. The hidden apps can be launched from a app designed for the same.

Comment: However, something like this would be useful as it would allow me to hide the crapware that came pre-installed on my device. I doubt that it is possible though.

Comment: Well, on the other hand launchers allow users to hide some icons from apps menu.

Comment: Do you want to "hide" *your* app's icon? - Or that of a third party?

Answer (score 6):

try to remove this line from your manifest

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: I don't think he has "try to remove this line from your manifest" in his manifest ;)